# POST http://localhost:5173/api/calculate.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, rest, backend, calculator, sveltekit

How can I fix it? I have correct directory and file format. What to do in this error please help me in API.

[image]

in Calculator.svelte

[image]

in calculator.json.js

[image]

in +page.svelte

[image]

Someone help my error in API.

Comment: Please copy code not the images

Answer (score 0):

First of all i'll just make an assumption that you're using the latest version av SvelteKit here.

So the problem seems to be with how you name your API files.

It seems that you have folder "api" with a file "calculate.json.js". So this is not really how SvelteKit works. So according to SvelteKit docs a file that is acting as an API should ALWAYS be named +server.js or +server.ts.

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server

So what you would do here is change the file structure to this:

```
– api
    - calculate
        - +server.js
```

This would give you the endpoint /api/calculate

If you really want it to be /api/calculate.json you could change the name of the "calculate" folder to "calculate.json". Howerver, that doesn't really make sense. That would imply that you're sending a POST request to a JSON file witch is a bit weird. I'd just advice to remove the .json part.

Hope it helps and otherwise feel free to get back to me :)

Also there is a few bugs in your server code. Change it to this and it should work fine.

```
export async function POST({request}) {
  const data = await request.json();
  const expression = data.expression;
  const previousValue = 0;
  const result = calculateResult(previousValue, expression);

  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ result }))
}
```

Comment: I did what you said, I renamed it as +server.js but it's the same. Honestly, the API code was made by AI so i dont have any idea of it. I just did a simple calculator but we were assigned to use API so when I did. it didn't work. I really appreciate your effort in helping me but can you please help me in to determine the problem by pushing my code https://github.com/xGwapito/Calculator.git I really appreciate you. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing @Joseph, thanks for sharing the code. Helps a lot.

So i found a couple of things. First of all. You have your `api` folder, in this folder you should create a `calculate` folder. And within that folder you want your +server.ts file. So what SvelteKit actually does here is to create the /api/calculate endpoint. The +server.ts is a magic file and will not be part of the URL.

After those changes you make a request to /api/calculate and it will work

PS. also check my edited answer, found a couple of errors in your server code there :)

Comment: @Joseph -- Never ever use AI-generated code when you're not experienced enough to evaluate the correctness. AI code-generation is a (controversial) tool only feasible for *advanced* programmers who know what they do and want to "outsource" some of the routine work. And it's disputed how much sense this makes at all. For beginners the usage of AI is deadly, as with no experience you won't even be able to formulate your requirements precisely enough, and therefore only get an abstract bunch of code you have no insight into, resulting in problems without end.